# Looping through dynamic columns and rows and transposing data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset that is dynamic, meaning N number of rows and N number of columns (groups). The first screenshot is how the data looks with 3 groups, but as I said it could be N number of groups. There can also be N number of items.

**Initial Data**:

[image]

The second screenshot shows how the data should look. I need to write the item name for every score (numeric value in that row). So I have to transpose the data somehow. I need to loop through the columns, but don't know how divide the groups in the loop since they have the same column headers. Only the definition and group number are always unique.

This has to be done in VBA.

**Final data after looping through rows and columns and "transposing"**:

[image]

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the code I've tried so far, which leaves spaces between the sets and only works for the first group.

```
    Sub transposeData()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim y As Long
Dim tempVal As Integer




Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1")


lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = ws.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 3 To lastRow Step 1
   For y = 3 To lastRow Step 1
    For j = 3 To lastCol Step 1

    If ws.Cells(i, j) <> vbNullString Then
    tempVal = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
    ws2.Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    ws2.Cells(y, 3) = tempVal
    ws2.Cells(y, "K") = ws.Cells(2, j).Value

    End If

    If tempVal <> 0 And tempVal - 1 Then
    y = y + 1
    End If

    If j = 41 Then
    i = i + 1
    End If

    tempVal = 0

    y = y

    Next j
    Next y
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post any code.  What has and hasn't worked? Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) thread on how to ask a "good" question, as this is not a "Code for me" site.

Comment: I know, I couldn't find the code as I was working on it at the office, so I re-wrote it quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took advantage of Excel's Transpose ability to get this code to work based on your sample data exactly as it is shown:

```
Sub Transpose()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Sheets("Sheet2")

ws2.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Name", "Value", "Test", "Defintion")

With ws1

    'how many groups are there so we know how many times to transpose
    'we find this out by counting the number of times "Defintion" appears
    Dim lDef As Long
    lDef = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(2), "Definition")

    'get last row where grouped data appears
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim l As Long
    For l = 3 To lRow 'loop through items

        Dim rDef As Range, sFirst As String
        Set rDef = .Rows(2).Find("Definition") 'find first instance of "Definition"
        sFirst = rDef.Address 'get address of first occurence so we can test if we reached it again

        'list Name (aka Item) (for as many rows as needed defined by how many groups * 4 (1 for each test))
        With ws2
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(4 * lDef).Value = ws1.Range("A" & l)
        End With


        Do

            'transpose values
            rDef.Offset(l - 2, 1).Resize(1, 4).Copy 'uses l-2 to offset for each row throughout the loop

            With ws2
                'paste values (test results)
                .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(4, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
                'load test cases
                .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(4, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"))
                'load definitions
                .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(4, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rDef.Offset(1).Value)
            End With

            Set rDef = .Rows(2).FindNext(After:=rDef) 'find next definition

        Loop Until rDef Is Nothing Or rDef.Address = sFirst

    Next


End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Drats, I was working on a macro too. Nice job though, I didn't think to actually use `Transpose` for some reason :P

Comment: This is interesting and looks like it could work (I can't adapt it at the moment but will later). Could you post the final result that you got by any chance?

Comment: Glad it works @MJ95. I was going to post the results, but I thought my first sentence was enough to explain that ... but I guess not :)

Comment: Yeah it was more for me to see if I explained it correctly, but the result was exactly what I was looking for, so thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this macro and see what you think about it. I copied your sample set and was able to duplicate your desired results using nested for loops.  Let me know if anything needs clarification.

```
Option Explicit

Sub customTransposing()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim startingRow As Integer
Dim startingColumn As Integer
Dim numberOfPoints As Integer
Dim numberOfEntries As Integer
Dim numberOfGroups As Integer
Dim outputRowOffset As Integer

' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' User Variables
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
startingRow = 3
startingColumn = 1
numberOfPoints = 4  ' The number of test points i.e. A B C D
numberOfEntries = 0
numberOfGroups = 3
outputRowOffset = 10
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


' Counts the number of entries in the first column
'   this section could most likely be improved
Cells(startingRow, startingColumn).Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then

        numberOfEntries = numberOfEntries + 1

    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop



For j = 0 To numberOfEntries - 1

    For k = 0 To numberOfGroups - 1

        For i = 0 To numberOfPoints - 1

                ' first column
                Cells(startingRow + numberOfEntries + (j * numberOfPoints * numberOfGroups) + outputRowOffset + i + k * numberOfPoints, startingColumn).Value = Cells(startingRow + j, startingColumn)
                ' second column
                Cells(startingRow + numberOfEntries + (j * numberOfPoints * numberOfGroups) + outputRowOffset + i + k * numberOfPoints, startingColumn + 1).Value = Cells(startingRow + j, startingColumn + 2 + i + k * (numberOfGroups + 2))
                ' third column
                Cells(startingRow + numberOfEntries + (j * numberOfPoints * numberOfGroups) + outputRowOffset + i + k * numberOfPoints, startingColumn + 2).Value = Cells(startingRow - 1, startingColumn + 2 + i)
                ' fourth column
                Cells(startingRow + numberOfEntries + (j * numberOfPoints * numberOfGroups) + outputRowOffset + i + k * numberOfPoints, startingColumn + 3).Value = Cells(startingRow + j, startingColumn + 1 + k * (numberOfGroups + 2))

        Next i

    Next k

Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: This most likely works (just from looking at it), but the problem is the numberofGroups is dynamic, as in it can be X number of groups, so I don't know the specific number. In the example I do, but in practice I won't

Comment: I did not see that you had already accepted an answer when I posted this solution.  But if you were able to count the number of groups, similarly to how I counted the entries, it would run with n groups.